# Query cf queryObject and insert into table

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, railo, lucee

I'm passing queryObject into a CFC. I can writeDump(myQryObject) and I see the queryObjects contents and all is good up to this point. I can write a select statement and dump a row(s) depending on my query - again, all good here. I need to now insert the data into a table but I'm not getting the syntax right.

The CFC is written in CFScript.

```
local.blkLoadQry = new Query(); // new query object     
local.blkLoadQry.setDBType("query");
local.blkLoadQry.setAttributes(sourceQuery=arguments.blkdata);
local.blkLoadQry.addParam(name="batchid",value=arguments.batchID,cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar",maxlength="36");

local.blkLoadQry.setSQL("
INSERT INTO bulkloadtemptable (
      uuid
      , gradyear
      , firstName
      , lastName
      , email
  )
  SELECT 
      :batchid
      , `Graduation Year`
      , `Jersey`
      , `First Name`
      , `Last Name`
      , `Email`
  FROM 
      bulkloadtemptable_copy
  WHERE uuid = :batchid
");

`Lexical error at line 10, column 17. Encountered: "`" (96), after : ""`
```

This is the error I'm getting but the line numbers of the errors don't line up with my expectations so that's what brings me here. :batchid would be line 10.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can use <pre></pre> to surround your code and keep the backticks where they belong.

Comment: First thing I noticed is you haven't specified a column for 'sourceQuery.Jersey' to be inserted into. You're trying to insert 6 values into 5 columns.

Comment: @AlexBaban - I'm new at using MySQL and haven't needed to use ` before so thank you for that feedback on how to post code using them.

Comment: @ultimoTG This turned out to the issue all along. :facepalm:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting something impossible.  Your query of queries select statement runs in ColdFusion only.  There is no database connection in play.

If you want to insert data from a ColdFusion query into a database, you have to loop through the rows somehow.  You can have an insert query inside a loop or a loop inside an insert query.  Here is sample syntax for both.

Query inside loop.

```
<cfoutput query="cfQueryObject">
<cfquery datasource = "aRealDatabase">
insert into table
(field1
, field2
, etc)
values
(<cfqueryparam value = "#cfQueryObject.field1#">
, <cfqueryparam value = "#cfQueryObject.field1#">
, etc
)
</cfquery>
</cfoutput>
```

Loop inside query

```
<cfquery datasource = "aRealDatabase">
insert into table
(field1
, field2
, etc)

select null
, null
, etc
from someSmallTable
where 1 = 2
<cfoutput query="cfQueryObject">
union
select <cfqueryparam value = "#cfQueryObject.field1#">
, <cfqueryparam value = "#cfQueryObject.field1#">
, etc
from someSmallTable
</cfoutput>
</cfquery>
```

You can experiment to see what works better in your situation.

Comment: Looping over the CF query object inside the insert query is probably best for performance as it requires only one connection.

Comment: Key word being `probably`.  I've done this a lot and seen it go both ways.

Comment: You'd expect 1 connection to be faster than 1000 if that's how many rows you have? But yes, I used `probably` advisedly as things don't always work as expected :-)

Comment: @DanBracuk - I assumed the select portion of the query would handle the looping. Perhaps I need to read more on this insertion technique but I don't understand why I need a loop? Also, the CFC is written entirely in CFScript so I need to update my question. I didn't even consider CFTags when I posted the question so I apologize for leaving that bit of detail out of my question.

Comment: The loop requirement is based on the assumption that the query object has more than one row.

Comment: Okay, I think I "get it" now

Comment: I converted the CFC to be tag based and the first solution posted worked great. For the dataset we have, the different in performance was negligible so we went with "Query inside loop" for ease in readability.